# Marshal.Release Exception and proper cleanup

Tags: c#, .net

I am extracting file thumbnail with following method. 
How do I properly perform the cleanup in this case: `DeleteObject(hbitmap);` or 
                `Marshal.Release(hbitmap);`

```
public ImageSource GetThumbnail(string mypath)
{
    IShellItem ppsi = null;
    IntPtr hbitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        Guid uuid = new Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe");
        SHCreateItemFromParsingName(mypath, IntPtr.Zero, uuid, out ppsi);
        ((IShellItemImageFactory)ppsi).GetImage(new SIZE(128, 128), SIIGBF.SIIGBF_THUMBNAILONLY, out hbitmap);

        BitmapSource source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        return source;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {               
        if (ppsi != null)                    
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ppsi);

        if (hbitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteObject(hbitmap); //this
            Marshal.Release(hbitmap); //this 
        }
    }            
}
```

On Marshal.Release I get

> Additional Information: An exception was caught but handled while
>   releasing a COM interface pointer through Marshal.Release,
>   Marshal.ReleaseComObject or implicitly after the corresponding
>   RuntimeCallableWrapper was garbage collected. This is the result of a
>   user refcount error or other problem with a COM object's Release. Make
>   sure refcounts are managed properly. While these types of exceptions
>   are caught by the CLR, they can still lead to corruption and data loss
>   so if possible the issue causing the exception should be addressed

Comment: Side-note: You should inspect the return value from `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` to ensure you get a valid response. Same with `IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage`.

Comment: [Just RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It explicitly tells you to use DeleteObject().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marshal.Release` is just for com objects, and a HBITMAP isn't one! `DeleteObject` is all you need.

Edit: As Hans Passant mentioned, read the manual:

> phbm [out]
>   Type: HBITMAP*
>
> Pointer to a value that, when this method returns successfully, receives the handle of the retrieved bitmap. It is the responsibility of the caller to free this retrieved resource through DeleteObject when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. I have found it used like this on so many places that I had to ask.